# Dart Error: NoSuchMethodError: '<Unexpected Null Value>'

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm having a lot of **"NoSuchMethodError: ''"** errors.

I have a big web application with angular. Now I'm using dart 2.6.1.
First I had a case in which I defined a `static const` variable (Ex. `static Duration period = Duration(seconds: 30);` ).

Using this variable caused that error. Removing the const keyword, everything seemed to work fine.
But then I got the same error from an angular component..

I have a lot of dependencies and I'm afraid that this is causing some strange problems to the compiler.

Any hint?

I don't know if there is a memory limit for const variables, in that case how could I check that limit (or increase it)? 
There something that I could do to verify what's the problem?
The following is a part of the stack trace:

```
Error_handler: reason NoSuchMethodError: '<Unexpected Null Value>'
method not found
Receiver: null
Arguments: [], exception, NoSuchMethodError: '<Unexpected Null Value>'
method not found
Receiver: null
Arguments: [], stack dart:sdk_internal                                                          createTimer
package:angular/src/core/change_detection/..%5Czone%5Cng_zone.dart 210:25  [_createTimer]
dart:sdk_internal                                                          new
package:angular_components/material_popup/material_popup.dart 510:25       [_onPopupOpened]
package:angular_components/material_popup/material_popup.dart 472:11       <fn>
package:stack_trace                                                        <fn>
package:angular/src/core/change_detection/..%5Czone%5Cng_zone.dart 144:18  <fn>
dart:sdk_internal                                                          runUnary
package:angular/src/core/change_detection/..%5Czone%5Cng_zone.dart 141:18  [_runUnary]
dart:sdk_internal                                                          add
package:angular_components/material_popup/material_popup.dart 862:29       <fn>
package:stack_trace                                                        <fn>
package:angular/src/core/change_detection/..%5Czone%5Cng_zone.dart 144:18  <fn>
dart:sdk_internal                                                          runUnary
package:angular/src/core/change_detection/..%5Czone%5Cng_zone.dart 141:18  [_runUnary]
package:stack_trace                                                        <fn>
package:angular/src/core/change_detection/..%5Czone%5Cng_zone.dart 144:18  <fn>
dart:sdk_internal                                                          runUnary
package:angular/src/core/change_detection/..%5Czone%5Cng_zone.dart 141:18  [_runUnary]
package:stack_trace                                                        <fn>
package:angular/src/core/change_detection/..%5Czone%5Cng_zone.dart 132:18  <fn>
dart:sdk_internal                                                          run
package:angular/src/core/change_detection/..%5Czone%5Cng_zone.dart 129:18  [_run]
dart:sdk_internal                                                          <fn>
package:angular/src/core/change_detection/..%5Czone%5Cng_zone.dart 117:11  <fn>
package:stack_trace                                                        <fn>
package:angular/src/core/change_detection/..%5Czone%5Cng_zone.dart 132:18  <fn>
dart:sdk_internal                                                          run
package:angular/src/core/change_detection/..%5Czone%5Cng_zone.dart 129:18  [_run]

dart:sdk_internal                                                          listen
package:angular_components/material_popup/material_popup.dart 468:50       [_open]
package:stack_trace                                                        <fn>
package:angular/src/core/change_detection/..%5Czone%5Cng_zone.dart 132:18  <fn>
dart:sdk_internal                                                          run
package:angular/src/core/change_detection/..%5Czone%5Cng_zone.dart 129:18  [_run]
dart:sdk_internal                                                          <fn>
package:angular/src/core/change_detection/..%5Czone%5Cng_zone.dart 117:11  <fn>
package:stack_trace                                                        <fn>
package:angular/src/core/change_detection/..%5Czone%5Cng_zone.dart 132:18  <fn>
dart:sdk_internal                                                          run
package:angular/src/core/change_detection/..%5Czone%5Cng_zone.dart 129:18  [_run]

dart:sdk_internal                                                                                                     scheduleMicrotask
package:angular_components/material_popup/material_popup.dart 338:9                                                   set visible
```

Edit 1:

I moved back to 2.5.2 and everything has worked fine. 
Then I installed  2.6.1 and the problem arose again.
So, I believe that is something related to 2.6.1

Comment: Did you resolve it? I encountered the same kind of issue. Wondering if you could help me out.

Comment: The problem disappeared with a newer Dart version (I do not remind if it was 2.8.0 or 2.7.1